# Find Scala Compile Version for maven-scala-plugin

Tags: scala, maven

Using the `maven-scala-plugin` how do I tell which Scala version is used for compiling?

I tried `mvn scala:help` per these [docs](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage.html), but the following error occurred:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scala-plugin' does not exist
 or no valid version could be found
```

Comment: Did you try that command in directory containing a `pom.xml` file? Does the `pom.xml` correctly includes a dependency for the maven-scala-plugin?

Comment: Yes, but it turned out that the `pom.xml` did not contain the `maven-scala-plugin`. I just re-ran `mvn scala:help` from a child `pom.xml` that contained the plugin. And it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I was suspecting something like that.